# How to use promises to wait for async API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am creating an API that when GET, a series of calls to the News API are made, news article titles are extracted into a giant string, and that string is processed into an object to be delivered to a wordcloud on the front-end. So far, I've been able to use underscore's `_.after` and request-promise to make my app wait till all API calls have completed before calling `processWordBank()` which takes the giant string and cleans it up into an object. However, once `processWordBank()` is called, I don't understand where the flow of the program is. Ideally, `processWordBank()` returns obj to cloudObj in the router, so that the obj can be passed to `res.json()` and spit out as the response. I believe my use of `_.after` has put me in a weird situation, but it's the only way I've been able to get async calls to finish before proceeding to next desired action. Any suggestions?

(I've tried to leave out all unnecessary code but let me know if this is insufficient)

```
// includes...
var sourceString = ""
// router
export default ({ config }) => {
  let news = Router()
  news.get('/', function(req, res){
    var cloudObj = getSources()
        res.json({ cloudObj })
  })
  return news
}

// create list of words (sourceString) by pulling news data from various sources
function getSources() {
    return getNewsApi()

}
// NEWS API
// GET top 10 news article titles from News API (news sources are determined by the values of newsApiSource array)
function getNewsApi() {
  var finished = _.after(newsApiSource.length, processWordBank)
  for(var i = 0; i < newsApiSource.length; i++) {
    let options = {
      uri: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + newsApiSource[i] + '&sortBy=' + rank + '&apiKey=' + apiKey,
      json: true
    }
    rp(options)
    .then(function (res) {
      let articles = res.articles // grab article objects from the response
      let articleTitles = " " + _.pluck(articles, 'title') // extract title of each news article
      sourceString += " " + articleTitles // add all titles to the word bank
      finished() // this async task has finished
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err)
    })
    }
}

// analyse word bank for patterns/trends
function processWordBank(){
  var sourceArray = refineSource(sourceString)
  sourceArray = combineCommon(sourceArray)
  sourceArray = getWordFreq(sourceArray)
  var obj = sortToObject(sourceArray[0], sourceArray[1])
  console.log(obj)
  return obj
}
```

Comment: instead of `finished()` try actually **returning** something ... perhaps `return finished()` - but then, you'll want `getNewsApi` to return something as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big issue in your asynchronous flow is that you use a shared variable `sourceString` to handle the results. When you have multiple calls to `getNewsApi()` your result is not predictable and will not always be the same, because there is no predefined order in which the asynchronous calls are executed. Not only that, but you never reset it, so all subsequent calls will also include the results of the previous calls. Avoid modifying shared variables in asynchronous calls and instead use the results directly.

> I've been able to use underscore's `_.after` and request-promise to make my app wait till all API calls have completed before calling `processWordBank()`

Although it would possible to use `_.after`, this can be done very nicely with promises, and since you're already using promises for your requests, it's just a matter of collecting the results from them. So because you want to wait until all API calls are completed you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which returns a promise that resolves with an array of the values of all the promises, once all of them are fulfilled. Let's have a look at a very simple example to see how [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) works:

```js
// Promise.resolve() creates a promise that is fulfilled with the given value
const p1 = Promise.resolve('a promise')
// A promise that completes after 1 second
const p2 = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('after 1 second'), 1000))
const p3 = Promise.resolve('hello').then(s => s + ' world')
const promises = [p1, p2, p3]

console.log('Waiting for all promises')
Promise.all(promises).then(results => console.log('All promises finished', results))
console.log('Promise.all does not block execution')
```

Now we can modify `getNewsApi()` to use `Promise.all`. The array of promises that is given to `Promise.all` are all the API request you're doing in your loop. This will be created with [Array.protoype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). And also instead of creating a string out of the array returned from `_.pluck`, we can just use the array directly, so you don't need to parse the string back to an array at the end.

```
function getNewsApi() {
  // Each element is a request promise
  const apiCalls = newsApiSource.map(function (source) {
    let options = {
      uri: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=' + source + '&sortBy=' + rank + '&apiKey=' + apiKey,
      json: true
    }
    return rp(options)
      .then(function (res) {
        let articles = res.articles
        let articleTitles = _.pluck(articles, 'title')
        // The promise is fulfilled with the articleTitles
        return articleTitles
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      })
  })
  // Return the promise that is fulfilled with all request values
  return Promise.all(apiCalls)
}
```

Then we need to use the values in the router. We know that the promise returned from `getNewsApi()` fulfils with an array of all the requests, which by themselves return an array of articles. That is a 2d array, but presumably you would want a 1d array with all the articles for your `processWordBank()` function, so we can flatten it first.

```
export default ({ config }) => {
  let news = Router()
  new.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const cloudObj = getSources()
    cloudObj.then(function (apiResponses) {
      // Flatten the array
      // From: [['source1article1', 'source1article2'], ['source2article1'], ...]
      // To: ['source1article1', 'source1article2', 'source2article1', ...]
      const articles = [].concat.apply([], apiResponses)
      // Pass the articles as parameter
      const processedArticles = processWordBank(articles)
      // Respond with the processed object
      res.json({ processedArticles })
    })
  })
}
```

And finally `processWordBank()` needs to be changed to use an input parameter instead of using the shared variable. `refineSource` is no longer needed, because you're already passing an array (unless you do some other modifications in it).

```
function processWordBank(articles) {
  let sourceArray = combineCommon(articles)
  sourceArray = getWordFreq(sourceArray)
  var obj = sortToObject(sourceArray[0], sourceArray[1])
  console.log(obj)
  return obj
}
```

---

As a bonus the router and `getNewsApi()` can be cleaned up with some [ES6 features](http://es6-features.org) (without the comments from the snippets above):

```
export default ({ config }) => {
  const news = Router()
  new.get('/', (req, res) => {
    getSources().then(apiResponses => {
      const articles = [].concat(...apiResponses)
      const processedArticles = processWordBank(articles)
      res.json({ processedArticles })
    })
  })
}

function getNewsApi() {
  const apiCalls = newsApiSource.map(source => {
    const options = {
      uri: `https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=${source}&sortBy=${rank}&apiKey=${apiKey}`,
      json: true
    }
    return rp(options)
      .then(res => _.pluck(res.articles, 'title'))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
  return Promise.all(apiCalls)
}
```

Comment: Dude this was super helpful. Helped wrap my head around using promises for API calls. Thank you!